# Как найти треугольник с максимальным периметром?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация

Даётся множество точек и надо найти треугольник с самым большим периметром (с вершинами в этих точках).
Входные данные: 2<n<101,
x и y не больше 10000

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    int n; 
    double max = 0;
    cin >> n; //Вводим к-во точек
    Point *g = new Point[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> g[i].x >> g[i].y; //Вводим координаты каждой точки
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
    {
        for (int h = 1 + i; h < n - 1; h++)
        {
            for (int j = 1 + h; j < n; j++)
            {
                double a = sqrt(pow(g[i].x - g[h].x, 2) + pow(g[i].y - g[h].y, 2)), b = sqrt(pow(g[i].x - g[j].x, 2) + pow(g[i].y - g[j].y, 2)), c = sqrt(pow(g[j].x - g[h].x, 2) + pow(g[j].y - g[h].y, 2)); //Считаем каждую сторону треугольника
                if (a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a) //Проверяем возможность существования такого треугольника
                {
                    double p = a + b + c;
                    if (p > max) //Находим максимальный периметр
                        max = p;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Оно проходит 19 тестов и стопорится. Скорее всего из-за времени. Как оптимизировать код?

Comment: Дайте-ка URL посмотреть.. Кстати, а зачем вы проверяете существование треугольника? Или точки могут совпадать?... Соптимизировать можно как минимум, считая расстояние между парой точек после второго цикла, и не пересчитывая его каждый раз. Кстати, можно и все расстояния считать сразу при вводе, чтоб потом не пересчитывать по сто раз одно и то же...

Comment: Есть подозрение что точки самого большого треугольника должны быть на выпуклой оболочке.
Кроме того у вас перебираются тройки точек, а можно перебирать (хитро) пары. Число точек не велико, видимо квадратичной сложности должно хватить.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Почему-то приходится выпрашивать URL... Так бы проверить собственные идеи за 5 минут, и ответ готов... :)

Comment: Что-то мне, кстати, не верится в тормоза. Если, конечно N действительно не более 100. Для 100 точек ваш код у меня на машине выдает результат за 32 мс — как-то ускорять тут вряд ли что-то требуется. Словом, без URL говорить не о чем...

Answer (score 1):

Что сразу бросается в глаза:

Я бы один раз вычислил расстояния между всеми парами точек и записал бы в двумерный массив

Comment: Без извлечения корней вы не сравните два периметра. Целочисленная арифметик тут погоды не сделает.

Comment: Более того, можно подобрать пары, когда a+b > c+d, но суммы квадратов дают обратное соотношение, так что искать по суммам квадратов, а вычислять реальный периметр потом не прокатит...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Там был еще первый пункт, где я пытался доказать, что можно сравнивать сумму квадратов. Потом я понял, что это не так и убрал его. А про следующий пункт забыл

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, вы не первый кто упирается лбом в сумму корней. В вычислительной геометрии почти все задачи сводятся к целочисленным вычислениям. Кроме задач со сравнением периметров: https://topp.openproblem.net/p33. Никто толком не знает как точно надо считать корни чтобы точно сравнить периметры.